# How can I wait for assets from CDN before showing a React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-helmet, react-native-stylesheet

I'm loading a stylesheet from an external CDN in order to style one page in React. The stylesheet link is injected to `<head`> using `react-helmet`:

```
<Helmet>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.com/site.css" />
</Helmet>
```

Unfortunately, before the stylesheet loads there's a FOUC visible for a few milliseconds. I'm integrating an outside service so I can't really load the style in any other way.

I've tried using `useEffect` hook and render page only when its ready like so:

```
const [isPageReady, setPageReady] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setPageReady(true);
}, []);

return ( 
  isPageReady && ( // my page );
)
```

But the FOUC is still there. Is there a way to wait for the stylesheet to load before I display the page?

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem is that the CSS is still loading while the first components are already on the screen. Usually this takes only a tiny fraction of a second, so you may just want to hide your components until the DOM is fully rendered.

To do this, you can encapsulate everything in a top-level div that's invisible until document.readyState equals complete. This way, the rendering of the DOM will not be visible and the first exposed screen will be a fully rendered document.

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState('hidden');

// This will run one time after the component mounts
useEffect(() => {
  const onPageLoad = () => {
    setVisible('visible');
  };
  // Check if the page has already loaded
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    onPageLoad();
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', onPageLoad);
    // Remove the event listener when component unmounts
    return () => window.removeEventListener('load', onPageLoad);
  }
}, []);

return (
  <div style={{ visibility: visible }}>
    <YourPage />
  </div>
);
```